# Accessing non-static objects from anonymous objects in Java

Tags: java, gwt, static, anonymous-class

Working with the Google Web Toolkit i have written an application which is based on the Model-View-Controller concept. Now my `ClientController` class has two objects of the types `ClientModel` and `ClientView` which are declared private and non-static. With an object for asynchronous calls i have written some Remote Procedure Calls which do work, however attaching an anonymous object from the type `AsyncCallback<T>` makes me a problem, as i can not access the two `ClientModel` and `ClientView` objects without writing some nasty `final` variables in my function like you can see below:

```
package com.foo.bar;

/**
 * Represents the main handler holding delegates and controlling the contents of
 * the {@link ClientModel} and pushes notifications and message to both the
 * {@link ClientModel} and the {@link ClientView}.
 */
public class ClientController {
    /**
     * Exposes asynchronous functions to call the server component via RPC.
     */
    public static final MyServiceAsync mySvc = GWT.create(myService.class);

    /**
     * Represents the model associated with the {@link ClientController} object.
     */
    private ClientModel theModel = null;
    /**
     * Represents the view associated with the {@link ClientController} object.
     */
    private ClientView theView = null;

    /**
     * Creates a new {@link ClientController} object and instantiates both the
     * {@link ClientModel} and the {@link ClientView}.
     */
    public ClientController() {
        this.theModel = new ClientModel();
        this.theView = new ClientView(this.theModel);
    }

    /* some more code */

    /**
     * Tries to login the specified user and updates the {@link ClientView}
     * object to either an error message or the main interface.
     * 
     * @param user
     *            {@link User} object representing the user to login
     */
    public void loginUser(final User user) {
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////
        // THIS IS UGLY AND I DON'T KNOW HOW TO FIX THIS
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////
        final ClientModel currentModel = this.theModel;

        // Execute the login protocol
        ClientController.mySvc.login(user, new AsyncCallback<Boolean>() {
            /**
             * The request was successfully executed. Returns a boolean value
             * indicating whether the user was logged in.
             * 
             * @param result
             *            true, if the user was logged in; otherwise, false.
             */
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Boolean result) {
                // The user was successfully logged in and we must both store
                // him in the model and then update the view.
                if (result) {
                    // TODO: Update the view to show the chat itself and save
                    // the current User to the ClientModel.
                    System.out.println("The User " + user.getUsername()
                            + " is now logged in!");
                    // Anonymous object can not access the theModel and theView
                    // objects of ClientController directly ...
                    // drunk, fix later!
                    // UGLY FIX FOR NOW
                    currentModel.setCurrentUser(user);
                } else {
                    // TODO: Unhide the error label of the login form and output
                    // some nice error message.
                    System.out.println("Login failed for User "
                            + user.getUsername() + "!");
                }
            }

            /**
             * The request provoked an error.
             */
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable up) {
                try {
                    throw up; // Ha ha
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    // Who cares?
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

For now I am using a final pointer to the internal model in `loginUser` which is hoghlighted two times. Can anyone explain me whether there is a better solution without moving `theModel` and `theView` to static members? It is annoying to write such "final wrappers" in every function you access either of the components...

Comment: What's nasty about final variables?

Comment: It's just the fact that I am forced to create temp vars which is quite annoying, redundant and therefore i hope i can find a more convenient workaround.

Comment: You should be able to fix this by declaring your fields final from the start: `private ClientModel theModel;` - Note that this works only if the model won't change anymore (as it then can't change).

Comment: @Thomas: Good point, however i am instantiating them in the `ClientController`'s constructor and furthermore the `ClientView` class's constructor takes the model as a parameter, which makes this more difficult to instantiate in one line.

Comment: Or simply make the necessary variables class fields. These can be accessed from within anonymous variables. **EDIT:** they already are class fields. The anonymous class should be able to access them. Please show us your full error message. **EDIT 2:** Your problem has nothing to do with final and all to do with static variables trying to access non-static. Get rid of the static. See answer.

Comment: @Christian, that's no problem. I'll add an answer with some code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create an instance of a *non-static* inner class, or an instance of an anonymous class, that instance has an implicit binding to the *instance* of the outer class that created it. You can access members of the outer class from within the inner class using `OuterClassName.this.member`.

In your case: `ClientController.this.theModel`

Comment: Although i am not familiar with this type of accessing members, it works!

Answer (score 0):

Try and declare your members final, like this:

```
...

private final ClientModel theModel;

private final ClientView theView;

public ClientController() {
    this.theModel = new ClientModel();
    this.theView = new ClientView(this.theModel);
}
```